# Dynamic hitbox in Flame Engine

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm making a clone qix game with flame. Currently i don't know how to get dynamic hitbox for the line. How can I detect self collision in Flame?

Original game: https://youtu.be/Wvzyd0OZg1I?t=69

[image: Gameplay]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use several `RectangleHitbox`es (easiest is if they are separate components if you are on v1) that you add to represent the line and then have the "head" as another hitbox (also on a separate component), probably a `CircleHitbox`. Then you override `onCollisionStart` in the head component and handle your logic in there.